# Magento 2.4.5 Community ain.CRITICAL: Error: Class "Locale" not found in DataBundle.php:64

Tags: magento

main.CRITICAL: Error: Class "Locale" not found in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64

Error while browsing magento site / admin url after deploying site successfully.

All below commands run without errors
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush